# Function is running one time in hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook like this :

```
    export default function AddSections ({ onCheckItem }) {

      const checkItem = (item) => {
console.log('check')

      }

      return (
 <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    className="section_item"
                    key={index}
                    id={section.name}
                    name="add-sections"
                    type="radio"
                    label={'section.label'}
                    value={'section.name'}
                    onChange={val => checkItem(item)}
                  />


        </div>
      )
    }
```

for the first time when i check the checkbox the function return the console.log, when i try to undo the check it never works

Comment: I don't see you using hooks at all.  Is that the correct code?

Comment: How does the Checkbox component look like?

Comment: you are calling a func on changing checkbox value , where you are using hooks!

Comment: That depends on what's in `Checkbox`. Where is that thing coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have defined the Checkbox type to be `radio` and you are using the uncontrolled input so it doesn't allow your to toggle.

You have two solutions

1. Change the type to `checkbox`

sample code:

```
export default function AddSections ({ onCheckItem }) {

      const checkItem = (item) => {
console.log('check')

      }

      return (
            <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    className="section_item"
                    key={index}
                    id={section.name}
                    name="add-sections"
                    type="checkbox"
                    label={'section.label'}
                    value={'section.name'}
                    onChange={val => checkItem(item)}
                  />


        </div>
      )
    }
```

2. Use Controlled input

sample code

```
export default function AddSections ({ onCheckItem }) {

      const [checked, setChecked] = useState('');
      const checkItem = (item) => {
          setChecked(checked => (checked == item? '': item));
      }

      return (
            <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    className="section_item"
                    key={index}
                    id={section.name}
                    name="add-sections"
                    checked={checked === item}
                    type="radio"
                    label={'section.label'}
                    value={'section.name'}
                    onChange={val => checkItem(item)}
                  />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `Checkbox` component is gonna map the props to native checkbox element. If that is the case, you should use `checked` prop as well. I don't see any hooks in your code though.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function AddSections ({ onCheckItem }) {

      const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

      const handleCheckItem = (item) => {
            setChecked(!checked)
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('clicked')
      }, [checked])

      return (
              <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    className="section_item"
                    key={index}
                    id={section.name}
                    name="add-sections"
                    type="radio"
                    label={'section.label'}
                    value={'section.name'}
                    checked={checked}
                    onChange={handleCheckItem}
                  />
        </div>
      )
    }
```